# Vue: Updating Array with ID of Parent Cell

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to change the gameBoard array upon selection of a number, but I'm having trouble with passing the id of the cell to change the appropriate index. Specifically, I would like to take the id of the parent cell-empty, and use that to compare it to the gameBoard array and change it to the value inputted. I'm struggling right now with passing on the id.

```
<template>
 <div> 
   <div class = "wrapper"> <div class= "list"  v-for="(n,index) in gameAnswer"> 
        <div  v-bind:id= "index" class = "cell-empty" v-if= "randomNumber(index)"> 
         <input type="text"> 
   </div>
  <div class = "cell"  v-else> {{n}}  </div>
  </div>
<br>
<br>
<div class = "list" v-for="n in gameBoard"> {{n}} </div>

    <br>
<br>
 <div class = "list" v-for="n in gameAnswer"> {{n}} </div>

 </div>  

</div>
</template>


<script>



 export default {
 name: 'sudoku',

 data: function(){
   return{
  gameAnswer: [4,3,5,2,6,9,7,8,1,6,8,2,5,7,1,4,9,3, 1,9,7,8,3,4,5,6,2, 8,2,6,1,9,5,3,4,7, 3,7,4,6,8,2,9,1,5,9,5,1,7,4,3,6,2,8,5,1,9,3,2,6,8,7,4, 2,4,8,9,5,7,1,3,6,7,6,3,4,1,8,2,5,9],
  gameBoard: [4,3,5,2,6,9,7,8,1,6,8,2,5,7,1,4,9,3, 1,9,7,8,3,4,5,6,2, 8,2,6,1,9,5,3,4,7, 3,7,4,6,8,2,9,1,5,9,5,1,7,4,3,6,2,8,5,1,9,3,2,6,8,7,4, 2,4,8,9,5,7,1,3,6,7,6,3,4,1,8,2,5,9],


   }
 },

  computed: {

 }
 },
  methods:{
    randomNumber: function(index){
  //  console.log(index);
    var val = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
    if(val == 0){
    this.gameBoard[index] = 0;
    return true;
  } else{
    return false;
  }
},

  changeVal(index){
     console.log(index);
  }

 },

 };

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to limitations in JavaScript, Vue cannot detect the following changes to an array:

When you directly set an item with the index, e.g. `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue` When you modify the length of the array, e.g. `vm.items.length = newLength`

For example:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  data: {
    items: ['a', 'b', 'c']
  }
})
vm.items[1] = 'x' // is NOT reactive
vm.items.length = 2 // is NOT reactive
```

To overcome caveat 1, both of the following will accomplish the same as `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue`, but will also trigger state updates in the reactivity system:

```
// Vue.set
Vue.set(vm.items, indexOfItem, newValue)
// Array.prototype.splice
vm.items.splice(indexOfItem, 1, newValue)
```

**Source**
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats

**Example**
I havent tested this but should work

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'sudoku',
        data () {
            return {
                gameAnswer: [4, 3, 5, 2, 6, 9, 7, 8, 1, 6, 8, 2, 5, 7, 1, 4, 9, 3, 1, 9, 7, 8, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 8, 2, 6, 1, 9, 5, 3, 4, 7, 3, 7, 4, 6, 8, 2, 9, 1, 5, 9, 5, 1, 7, 4, 3, 6, 2, 8, 5, 1, 9, 3, 2, 6, 8, 7, 4, 2, 4, 8, 9, 5, 7, 1, 3, 6, 7, 6, 3, 4, 1, 8, 2, 5, 9],
                gameBoard: [4, 3, 5, 2, 6, 9, 7, 8, 1, 6, 8, 2, 5, 7, 1, 4, 9, 3, 1, 9, 7, 8, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 8, 2, 6, 1, 9, 5, 3, 4, 7, 3, 7, 4, 6, 8, 2, 9, 1, 5, 9, 5, 1, 7, 4, 3, 6, 2, 8, 5, 1, 9, 3, 2, 6, 8, 7, 4, 2, 4, 8, 9, 5, 7, 1, 3, 6, 7, 6, 3, 4, 1, 8, 2, 5, 9]
            }
        },
        methods: {
            randomNumber (index) {
                var val = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
                if (val === 0) {
                    this.$set(this.gameBoard, index, 0)
                    return true
                } else {
                    return false
                }
            },
            changeVal (index, number) {
                this.$set(this.gameBoard, index, number)
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <div class="wrapper"> 
            <div class="list"  v-for="(number,index) in gameAnswer" :key="index"> 
                <div  v-bind:id="index" class="cell-empty" v-if="randomNumber(index)"> 
                    <input type="text" v-on:keyup="changeVal( index, number)"> 
                </div>
                <div class="cell"  v-else> 
                    {{number}}  
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="list" v-for="(number, index) in gameBoard" :key="index"> 
                {{number}} 
            </div>
            
            <div class="list" v-for="(number, index) in gameAnswer" :key="index"> 
                {{number}} 
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</template>
```